# Dropwizard State-less JWT based authentication

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ldap, jwt, dropwizard

I am new to Dropwizard, have to implement authentication and authorization using JWT and LDAP. I am Using Dropwizard version 1.0.2 ,Front-end is AngularJs here.

The idea is to have JWT based state-less authentication b/w angular and Dropwizard. As it is an internal application I do expect token to expire, however a subsequent request will be intercepted and will be send to LDAP and a fresh token needs to be generated and send back to client.

i have looked at this link http://jarbytes.com/jwt-on-dropwizard.html  but this  does not use dropwizard-auth module

Question : how to implement JWT based authentication in drop-wizard. How I can add authentication to all the resources without adding @Auth on all resources. How to intercept request and check for token and set token back as response if required

Design question : Should we use basic authentication or oauth2 here?

Comment: https://github.com/ToastShaman/dropwizard-auth-jwt - Check this projects. The example application mentioned in the README.md is in the `/src/test` forlder: https://github.com/ToastShaman/dropwizard-auth-jwt/tree/master/src/test/java/com/github/toastshaman/dropwizard/auth/jwt/example

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not clear how are we intercepting the request in case of good Token. So what I mean to say in case you have a Valid token, I need it to redirect to the business URL (similar to http filtering) . How do we achieve this here ?